# Что делают с памятью(Davlik) приложения типа Clean Master(Boost)?

Tags: android, android-fragment

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мое приложение с фрагментами сворачивается и восстанавливается нормально.
Но если свернуть его и вызвать приложение очистки памяти и развернуть мое приложение(или запустить с ярлыка), то фрагменты начинают накладываться друг на дружку при их вызове. Странно, ведь вызывается onCreate() и поэтому приложение должно работать как новое только запущенное.
Заменяются фрагменты следующим образом:

```
FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frgMainMenu);
fTrans.commit();
```

Comment: то, что фрагменты накладываются - это видно визуально?

А подобные поделки обычно просто пытаются завершить все процессы (не всегда правильно) или пытаются занять побольше памяти, что бы система вытеснила все другие процессы, а потом просто отдают системе память назад.

Comment: Да. Например фрагмент с текстом появляется над фрагментом с кнопками). Работает так будто в место  `fTrans.replace()` используется `fTrans.add()`

Comment: есть подозрение, что у Вас где то используются статические переменные или Вы на них полагаетесь.

Comment: А у кого их нет? :) В Main_Activity есть пара. Но к фрагментам и их вызову они не относятся.

Comment: Как считаете при использовании Clean Master у приложения вызывается `onDestroy()`?  logcat последним видит `onStop()` и дальше приложения пропадает из виду logcat. Может в `onDestroy()` можно как-то правильно завершить приложение?

Comment: согласно документации, onDestroy может не вызываться даже при обычной работе. Если Вы там выставляете какие-то флажки, на которые потом полагаетесь - это может быть причиной багов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зайдите в настройки телефона, опции разработчика и установите `Лимит фоновых процессов` в ноль.

Теперь если вы свернет свое приложение, запустите и любое другое, система очистит память вашего приложение. После этого разворачивайте его и дебажте/читайте логи чтобы установить причину ошибки.

В конце не забудьте вернуть параметру `Лимит фоновых процессов` начальное значение иначе телефон будет тупить.

По поводу наслаивания фрагментов - при восстановлении после убийства процесса есть стандартный механизм восстановления состояния, скорее всего вы его не учитываете.

UPD. По поводу стандартного механизма восстановления, это происходит тут:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Если приложение было убито и восстанавливается, то параметр savedInstanceState будет не null. Следовательно можете добавить проверку `if (savedInstanceState != null) {..}` - не добавлять ваши фрагменты.

Comment: Супер, спасибо у меня эта установка звучит "No background processes". С ней глючит так же :)

Comment: Сам ответил на свой вопрос, а потом обновил и увидел ваш отредактированный :). Собственно вывод я сделал правильный. Спасибо.

Comment: Что бы убить приложение не обязательно выставлять лимит в 0. Если используется AndroidStudio, то там есть кнопка TerminateApplication, нажав на которую получится тот же эффект.  Находится она во вкладке Android Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем получилось так `onDestroy()` не вызывается во время убийства приложения он вообще не вызывается. Отслеживаем так:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String flag = preferences.getString("kill", null);
        if(flag!=null && flag.equals("yes")){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "was onDestroy()");
        }
    }    
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("kill", "yes");
    }
```

Насколько я понял, после убийства настройки сохраняются в Bundle и возвращаются при повторном запуске приложения через `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` Тут то у меня я возникает лажа. Так, что перед передачей `savedInstanceState` в `super.onCreate();` я присвоил ему значение `null`. Если же процесс не был убит системой то приложение разворачивается с места разрыва через `onStart()` минуя `onCreate()`